# academic dismissive undergraduate and research experience

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, cv, research-undergraduate

I've got an academic dismissive (LOW GPA) from the department at my 2nd year of my undergraduate study due to money problems, then I got back to the program and raised my GPA from 1.9 to 3.2 (overall GPA). 
Step by step, my GPA at the last 60 hours was 3.75> I overcame the problem because I've found a good job from home. 
I worked as a research assistant for one year with two of my professors, had a 8 weeks internship in a good institution in London, had a 6 weeks internship in my country, and studied well for the exam so I've got 100 out of 120 in the TOFEL exam and 170 for the Q part, 153 for the V part of the GRE exam.

I want to take a Master of Science in materials engineering or aerospace materials, and then continue to PHD.

Please tell me if the dismissive mistake will effect the master's admission negatively?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE Academia. I understand you're upset about this topic, however we'd need clearer information to provide any useful feedback. Please revisit your post, and focus on a specific questions. You can break it down by posting different questions, if it would make this easier. Right now it reads very confusing.

Comment: Please avoid vandalizing your question. It's useless and would only lead to suspension.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper answer will come from the admissions system of a university that you apply to. However, in any system that lets you make a personal statement or (better) includes an interview, you will have a chance to explain the issue. Most people, though not everyone, will understand that people change and grow. They also, normally, understand that the more recent work is a better indication of your future work.

I wouldn't worry too much about it, as long as you have a satisfactory explanation and have made up any learning deficit you may have from the year of poor work.